# php form submit issue with JS button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have this form

```
 <form role="form" method='post' action='index.php' id='cme'>
    <input type="hidden" name="bonval" value="<?php echo $bonval ?>" />
    <fieldset>
        <h2 class="blink_me" style="color:green;font-size:40px;"><?php echo $bonval ?></h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <center>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="siteky"></div>
            </center>
        </div>
         <div class="row">
            <center>
                <input type="submit" name="claim" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Claim Now" id="claim">
            </center>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I have this javascript to disable button after click

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#claim').on('click',function(){
        $(this).val('Please wait ...')
        .attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#cme').submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is my form validation

```
 if(isset($_POST['claim'])) {
$recaptcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
if(!empty($recaptcha)) {
    # Use the recaptcha function here
    $resp   =   getGoogleRecaptcha();
    if($resp['success']) {
        # Capture value from the form submit
        $bonval =   $_POST['bonval'];
        # Insert normally
        $db->fetchVal("insert into log (`user_id`,`amount`) values (?,?)", array($id, $bonval));
    } 
  } else { ?>
  <div class="overlay"><div class="popup" style="background:red;">
    <h2>Error</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <div> <center><span class="blink_me">Seems error</span></center></div>
  </div></div>  
   <?php  }
  }
```

1. My issue is button gets disabled but form is not submitted
2. if user refresh page form keeps getting submitted into database

Answer (score 1):

Edit: sorry, lack of explanation, I read a little fast:

You can completely remove the var $ _POST after insert bdd with unset($_POST['...']);

```
if(isset($_POST['claim'])) {
    //code

    $db->fetchVal("insert into log (`user_id`,`amount`) values (?,?)", array($id, $bonval));

    unset($_POST['claim']);

    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should stop the button from submitting form first by replacing the `type="submit"` by `type="button"` :

```
<input type="button" name="claim" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Claim Now" id="claim">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But form is not being sent (form validation)

Comment: `$('#cme').submit()` should submit the form to the php page that will make the validations not ?!

Comment: `<input type="button" name="claim" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Claim Now" id="claim">`   added this and utton not work now and form action is `self` index.php page but no it does not send

Comment: Button should work normal like https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/363/ .. check this one using timeout just to see what happen https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/364/

Comment: I do not know much php or javascript so if you can do some kindness of fiddle plz to solve this issue

Comment: button now works perfect but form not submitted ... means no action on form is done.... Am i putting  `if(isset($_POST['claim'])) {`  wrongly in wrong place or something else which is causing issue, as if i disable javascript form works nice

Comment: tried different things and only answer comes to my thinking is this javascript is unable to submit form submission...plz guide me what i am doing wrong

Comment: I'm really sorry but can't see what you want to achieve here, try to describe you desired behaviour so i could helps... aldo please check `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];` you 're trying toget `g-recaptcha-response` param when there's no field with this name in the shown form.

Comment: if i do not use this javascript my form works but if i use it form does not work which means no issue with fields or values, only issue seems some colission of coe or my non sense which is not allowing things to work

Comment: I am trying to do is .... 1. Disable submit button after one click   2. disable user ability to resubmit form on page refresh

Comment: now issue is form submit not working  and user able to submit form on page refresh

Comment: The second point _disable user ability to resubmit form on page refresh_ needs the use of cookies or localStorage.